# Ubuntu 20.04 not showing login option to change desktop evirornment

Tags: login, desktop-environments, login-screen

As the title says, the icon on the bottom right of the login screen is not showing at all.

It was not showing from the default installation nor after installing BSPWM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @PRATAP it was not showing from the default installation nor now that I installed BSPWM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to be fully logged out to be able to change the desktop environment. The Gear Symbol should then be there.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.
Whether after a logout or after a restart, the screen just shows a list of users . . .

I've noticed the cog in the persistent Ubuntu installation disk but never for a fully installed system.

### EDIT

The trick is to log out.

Then click on the part where you enter a password for the user.

Once you have clicked in here, the cog shows itself at the bottom right of the screen.

[image]